# Meaning of "tmp$xxxx" in Mathematica output

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

As it is problematic to google strings which contain `$` (dollar sign) I couldn't find any explanation to the following output:

```
{Cos[tmp$132923 + \[Phi]], 
 Sin[tmp$132926 + \[Phi]], 
\[Phi]
}
```

#### The question:

*What does `tmp$xxxx` means?*

#### Some background

In `book2.nb' I defined the following function:

```
g[i_, j_] := {
  f1[i, t, f2[b, j], p][[1]],
  f1[i, t, f2[b, j], p][[2]],
  f3[i, t, p]
  }
```

Where `f1,f2,f3` are all defined in another notebook `book1.nb`, which was initialized and working fine. Furthermore, `f1` returns a list and `b` is a list defined and active.

Now, when I invoke `g[1,1]` I get an output similar to the one cited above - with this `tmp$`. Nevertheless, if I try to plot `g` it works perfectly (using `ParametricPlot3D[g[1, 1], {t, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}]`). However, if I try to define a variable

```
V= {
      f1[1, t, f2[b, 1], p][[1]],
      f1[1, t, f2[b, 1], p][[2]],
      f3[1, t, p]
      }
```

where I replace `i,j` with fixed values. Then `V` is once again with a `tmp$` element, but this time it DOESN'T plot...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code probably has a variation of this problem:

```
f[x_] := Module[{t}, Cos[t]+Cos[x] ]
```

at which point evaluating this:

```
f[y]
```

gives this:

```
Cos[t$685] + Cos[y]
```

Often, this means there is a problem with the code.

Either 't' was meant to be passed in as a parameter of 'f':

```
f[x_,t_] := Module[{}, Cos[t]+Cos[x] ]
```

or 't' needed to be initialized in some fashion:

```
f[x_] := Module[{t}, t=2x; Cos[t]+Cos[x] ]
```

It's perfectly ok to use these unique variables in your code, if you intend to do so. For example, this is one way to write an expression with with many unique variables:

```
Plus @@ Table[Unique[x]^i, {i, 100}]
```

Answer (score 9):

You are most likely seeing localized symbols that result through scoping such as `Module`.

Here is one example.  Since the localized symbol `x` is used to define the global symbol `y` the temporary symbol `x$152` escapes `Module`.

```
In[1]:= Module[{x}, y = x]; y

Out[2]= x$152
```

There are other variations of this process.  Suppose you set a unique context for the cell (`Evaluation` > `Notebook's Default Context` > `Unique to Each Cell Group`) and then make an assignment to an explicitly Global symbol:

```
Global`b = a
```

Now in another notebook:

```
In[1]:= b

Out[1]= Notebook$$33`a
```

Comment: +1, for "escapes `Module`." I hate it when variables chew through their restraints ...